# View Filters' OR operator not applied

Tags: 8, views

I created a content view that has a filter group using the AND operator that is ANDed with another filter group using the OR operator (see image below)

[image]

However, the query constructed is all AND operators and groups aren't even applied. Here is the WHERE clause of the query:

```
WHERE 
(
  (
    // Content: Type (= On-demand)
    node__field_format.field_format_target_id = '29'
  )
) 
AND 
(
  (
    (
      // Content: Published (= Yes)
      "node_field_data"."status" = '1'
    )
    AND 
    (
      // Content: Content type (in Event, Training)
      "node_field_data"."type" IN ('event', 'training_session')
    )
  ) 
  AND
  (
    (
      // (field_date_and_location: Paragraph) Paragraph: Date Range (>= + 0 minutes)
      DATE_FORMAT((paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_date_and_location__paragraph__field_date_range.field_date_range_value + INTERVAL -21600 SECOND), '%Y-%m-%d\T%H:%i:%s') >= DATE_FORMAT(('2021-10-19T18:53:48' + INTERVAL -21600 SECOND), '%Y-%m-%d\T%H:%i:%s')
    )
  )
)
```

This query isn't even remotely close to what I have it configured as... By my configurations, I would expect the WHERE clause to be

```
WHERE 
(
  (
    // Content: Published (= Yes)
    "node_field_data"."status" = '1'
  )
  AND 
  (
    // Content: Content type (in Event, Training)
    "node_field_data"."type" IN ('event', 'training_session')
  )
) 
AND 
(
  (
    // Content: Type (= On-demand)
    node__field_format.field_format_target_id = '29'
  ) 
  OR
  (
    // (field_date_and_location: Paragraph) Paragraph: Date Range (>= + 0 minutes)
    DATE_FORMAT((paragraphs_item_field_data_node__field_date_and_location__paragraph__field_date_range.field_date_range_value + INTERVAL -21600 SECOND), '%Y-%m-%d\T%H:%i:%s') >= DATE_FORMAT(('2021-10-19T18:53:48' + INTERVAL -21600 SECOND), '%Y-%m-%d\T%H:%i:%s')
  )
)
```

What's the issue with my configurations? I feel this should be pretty a straightforward implementation but the degree to which the query is incorrect seems off..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Drupal has a bug in their code. The content type we are displaying has a couple of `Types` which is a taxonomy term. If a record has an `On Demand` taxonomy type, it does not have a Date. However, when displaying this list we need to display all content with a date in the future OR has the 'On Demand' taxonomy type.

In addition, we have an exposed filter that allows a user to filter by this taxonomy term type. Therefore, there are two separate filters on the same field, one is exposed the other is not.

In the first condition group, there exists an exposed filter condition called `Has Taxonomy Term` that is looking at the `Topic` taxonomy term.

In the second condition group, there exists a non-exposed filter condition called `Content: Type` that is also looking at the `Topic` taxonomy term.

However, when Drupal builds up this where clause. it puts the `Content Type == On Demand` condition into the condition group where the similar exposed filter exists.

You MUST fix this in `hook_views_query_alter`. I have reported this as a bug on Drupal.org